# Evaluating Greater Than x But Less Than x VBA

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I am building an application which must interpret a set of instructions set by the user, instructions which will not be known until runtime.

I am achieving this by using the Evaluate function, as so:

```
Evaluate("5>4")
```

Which returns True, as one would expect. My question is how do I evaluate the following statement:

5 is greater than 4, but less than 10

I will be substituting the numbers with variables, of course.

I realise I could split the string into an array of two parts and test individually, but there must be a way of passing a single argument to test.

Comment: maybe like this? `Evaluate("10>5>4")`

Comment: That doesn't work because Evaluate("10>10>4") also returns True

Comment: I'm sure there's a reason why you can't use the and operator, can I ask what it is?

Comment: @tompreston I've just tried Evaluate(5>4 and 5<10) which does work, but the user will be entering as a string in a field. How will i convert into this formula because the follow does not work Evaluate("5>4" and "5<10")

Comment: try this: Debug.Print Evaluate("10>4") And Evaluate("4>2")

Comment: Thanks Tom, this does work, but as mentioned in the question, I want to avoid splitting the string into an array and creating separate evaluations if possible. Perhaps I will need to

Comment: Oh god, missed that part- D'oh!  Good luck all the same

Comment: How many operators are allowed in your expressions? You should limit yourslef to a very simple grammar, otherwise, you should write your own expression evaluator, that's a huge task.

Comment: Just two. I was part of the way through writing my own evaluator, then I discovered the Evaluate function. I can write a simplified evaluator using the Evaluate function, i think this is what i'll end up doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Application.Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019) evaluates Formulas so `AND(5>A4,5<10)` or `(5>A4)*(5<10)` (results in 0 or 1)

Another alternative could be [`ScriptControl Eval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227633), but it can't access Excel addresses like `Evaluate`

```
With CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    .Language = "VBScript"              ' either VBScript or JScript
    Debug.Print .Eval("5>4 and 5<10")
End With
```

Comment: Amazing. Didn't know about the SC